# HTML creating a table by data binding a csv file to a table

Tags: html, file, csv, html-table

I copied this code from a book its supposed to create a formatted table from a simple csv text file which I will detail at the end. It does create the table but all the rows are collapsed or the text is missing except for the heading row. I'm a beginner so I can't see the problem especially since it from a book.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Data Binding Example</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<!-- validation not possible due to datasrc and datfld attributes -->
</head>
<body>
<object id="alphabet"
        classid="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83">
     <param name= "DataURL" value="alphabet.txt" />
  <param name= "UseHeader" value="True" />
</object>

<table datasrc="#alphabet" border="1">
<thead>
   <tr bgcolor="yellow">
   <th>Letter</th>
   <th>Reminder</th>
   </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr align="center">
    <td><span datafld="Letter"></span></td>
    <td><span datafld="Thing"></span></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need either a web server or a javascript code to read from file and serialize data to display in table. Object tag is to embed multimedia (like pdf, audio, video).

Comment: The csv file is in the same folder on my computer as the html file so it does read the file and create the page with the table but only the heading data is inserted in the table

Comment: To serialize the data in the csv file, you need to run code. You need to read data line by line, separate columns according to the separator used in the csv file and insert it cell by cell. This can be done using code, html does not do this automatically.